# Jenkins pipeline create directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to know if there is a function or pipeline plugin that allows to create directory under the workspace instead of using `sh "mkdir directory"`?

I've tried to use a groovy instruction `new File("directory").mkdirs()` but it always return an exception.

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.lang.RuntimeException java.lang.String

Comment: The exception is thrown because you need to explicitly whitelist that script/module: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/

Comment: also, if running on a node, that directory will be created on the master.  Groovy CPS means that groovy code executes on master and is transported over to the node.  So, File is fine for constructing paths and dangerous/misleading otherwise.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

What you can do is use the `dir` step, if the directory doesn't exist, then the `dir` step will create the folders needed once you write a file or similar:

```
node {
    sh 'ls -l'
    dir ('foo') {
        writeFile file:'dummy', text:''
    }
    sh 'ls -l'
}
```

The `sh` steps is just there to show that the folder is created. The downside is that you will have a dummy file in the folder (the dummy write is not necessary if you're going to write other files). If I run this I get the following output:

```
Started by user jon
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pl
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[pl] Running shell script
+ ls -l
total 0
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pl/foo
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] writeFile
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] sh
[pl] Running shell script
+ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Mar  7 22:06 foo
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the closure for `dir` can be an empty statement, but you don't have to create a file - I just reported the current directory for logging purposes.

Comment: Did some testing, no it can not. Seems like the directory is created when you use a step which requires file context, e.g. sh, writeFile, etc... So if you only use echo and other non-node requiring steps, then the directory will not be created.

Comment: Ah I was using `sh 'echo $(pwd -P)'` to log where the directory was :)

Comment: Another gotcha: steps inside the `dir` block will execute with current directory set to the specified directory. So one can't just put logic inside the block if that logic has to be run with current directory set to workspace.

Answer (score 8):

Just use a [file operations plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-operations).

```
fileOperations([folderCreateOperation('directoryname')])
```

Comment: Just for the directory creation it is easier to use the pipeline's dir { }. However mentioning of this plugin is also interesting, because it can perform many other file operations on a node.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the dummy file from the answer by @jon-s, one could simply `pwd -P`. That also accesses the directory and therefore creates it implicitly.

```
dir('foo') {
   sh 'pwd -P'
}
```

Notes:

- It seems `-P` is needed. Assumedly, `pwd` just passes the environment variable otherwise.
- One could argue that `sh 'mkdir -p foo'` is equally suitable (if using `sh` at all).